# UITableView delegate fires NSURLConnection delegate

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

i fetch data via NSURLConnction from a server and want to populate a tableview from fetched array. The data appears in the log from NSURLConnection delegate method but i realized that `numberOfRowsInSection` of UITableView delegate method(DM) fires before

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {}
```

DM of NSURLConnection. and this causes a problem for me because even tough i get the data properly returned number of rows is allways 0(zero).. How can i solve this issue please share any idea.. Thanks

Comment: call [tableView reloadData]; at the end of -connection:didReceiveData:

Comment: @Moxy thanks. you could give as answer too. it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

didRecieveData might be called more than once, and does not indicates that all data is fetched. You should implement a private property on your class such as;

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableData tableData;
```

and on your didRecieveData;

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   [self.tableData appendData:data];
}
```

After that when your connection is closed

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // use tableData and refresh table...
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `[tableView reloadData];` at the end of `-connection:didReceiveData:` in order to update your table view.

Edit: Bartu is right!
You need to call it at the end of `-connectionDidFinishLoading:`